# Diagonalizing a real normal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, orthonormal

Given the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$, how would I find a real orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $PAP^t$ is a diagonal matrix?

I've found the eigenvalues  $0, \dfrac{9\pm\sqrt{105}}{2}$, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Did you try RREF of $A - \lambda I$?

Answer (score 0):

There exists a basis of eigenvectors since $A$ is symmetric.   Form an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.  Form the matrix whose columns are the basis vectors,  as your $P$.

Comment: How do you form this orthonormal basis of eigenvectors?

Comment: For each eigenvalue $\lambda$, find the kernel of $A-\lambda I$.  Get three linearly independent eigenvectors,  then use Gram-schmidt.